# insert trigger not working

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have the following table and trigger but the trigger isn't setting the create_dt value to now() on the insert event:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `modify_by` int(10) NOT NULL default '1',
  `modify_dt` timestamp NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `create_by` int(10) NOT NULL default '1',
  `create_dt` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `active` enum('Yes','No') NOT NULL default 'No',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`modify_by`) REFERENCES `user`(`user_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`create_by`) REFERENCES `user`(`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;


CREATE TRIGGER ins_user BEFORE INSERT ON `user` FOR EACH ROW SET @create_dt = NOW();
```

I've tried both BEFORE and AFTER trigger action time but no change.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

The goal is to have the create_dt value set with a date_time NOW() value on insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `@create_dt` sets a variable. You want to `SET NEW.create_dt = NOW()`. This will change the value of the incoming record.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I new it was something simple. Just didn't know what it was.  Thanks for the help!